# Custom sidebars - get_sidebar() problems

Tags: sidebar, metabox, register-sidebar

I want to have different sidebars on different pages.

So firstly I registered a few basic sidebars in functions.php. So they will be always there no matter where I move my theme. Let's name them Standard Sidebar, Special Sidebar, Tiny Sidebar.

The next step was creating sidebars metabox below posts and pages. It lists all the sidebars using foreach $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars'] loop and allows user to pick one.

Now, here comes the trouble.

I don't know how to display my sidebars.

I have a meta value but get_sidebar() accepts only names from sidebar.php file.

What about registered (not included in sidebar.php) sidebars?

I know I could add all my sidebars to sidebar.php/save them as sidebar-name.php, but again, I'm going to use sidebar generator to add addtional sidebars to three basic ones.

Any ideas, walk-troughs how to accomplish this? Displaying registered sidebars by name will be a serious breakthrough in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call registered sidebars with the dynamic_sidebar() function. Just put the ID of the sidebar in to the call. In the case below the id would be homepage-sidebar.

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('homepage-sidebar') ) : ?><?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `dynamic_sidebar()` is really old function by now, it's well time to stop checking if it exists. :) This just gets passed on as arcane spell...

Comment: fair enough I've just had the snippet stored for a while and haven't bothered to change it.

Comment: Oh my God, I've been so blind ;/ In fact I found the same code @curtismchale gave in my own sidebar.php file... Just moved it from there to page.php... Thanks a lot guys, +1 :)

Comment: @Wordpressor rather than moving it to page.php you should stil call get_sidebar() and put your conditionals in sidebar.php.